# How to use for loop to count number

Tags: c

I would like to write a program that can continuously + 1 to ID once user registered a user. I use `for loop` to design it, but I don't know how to break the loop after registered a user. Please help me.

Expected Data in **idtest.txt:**

```
SID001:USER1
SID002:USER2
SID003:USER3
.
.
and so on
```

Actual Data in **idtest.txt:**

```
SID001:USER1
SID002:USER1
SID003:USER1
.
until SID00999:USER1
```

**My Code:**

```
int main()
{
    FILE* f;
    char data[1024], user[50];
    int num = 0, c, buf;

    printf("Enter User: ");
    scanf("%s", user);

    f = fopen("idtest.txt", "a+");
    while (fgets(data, sizeof data, f));

    for (buf = 1; buf <= 999; buf++)
    {
        c = fgetc(f);
        if (c == EOF)
        {
            fprintf(f, "SID00%d:%s\n", num, user);
        }
        else if (num >= 1)
        {
            fprintf(f, "SID00%d:%s\n", num, user);
        }
        else if (num >= 9)
        {
            fprintf(f, "SID0%d:%s\n", num, user);
        }
        else if (num >= 99)
        {
            fprintf(f, "SID%d:%s\n", num, user);
        }
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You aren't changing what's stored in `user` in the for loop. "I don't know how to break the loop after registered a user": You'd want to use `break` for that.

Comment: @JustASimpleLonelyProgrammer Hi, I change the code already.. But it still not working

Comment: 0. You still aren't changing what's stored in `user` in the for loop. 1. You're breaking the loop just after the first iteration. 2. You never change `num`, so `num` is always 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you do not test for errors
- as coded, `num` is always `0`: the program cannot produce the file contents you posted.
- it makes no sense to try an read the next byte with `fgetc(f)` since the previous loop reached the end of the file already. This call returns `EOF`, which explains why you always write 2 leading zeroes.
- you cannot mix reading and writing operations without an intervening seek operation, it has undefined behavior. Your code manages to write to the file, but it might behave differently with a different compiler / library / operating system...
- you can simplify the output code using `%03d` to format numbers with leading zeroes.
- naming an `int` variable `buf` is very confusing.

If you intend for the program to register one user at a time, you should read the file and count the number of lines, then write a single entry at the end.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char user[50];
    char data[1024];
    FILE *f;
    int num;

    printf("Enter User: ");
    if (scanf("%49s", user) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid or missing input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    f = fopen("idtest.txt", "a+");
    if (f == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open file idtest.txt\n");
        return 1;
    }
    /* count the number of users */
    num = 1;
    rewind(f);
    while (fgets(data, sizeof data, f)) {
        num++;
    }
    /* switch to writing mode */

    // No need to seek because the above loop hit the end of file.
    // which is a special case where the next call can be a write operation
    //fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_CUR);

    fprintf(f, "SID%03d:%s\n", num, user);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you explanation. I tried your code, but it keep looping **SID999**. My expectation is when user register one people then the loop break out. When I open back for register another people, it read the latest ID and plus one.. So, how to break the loop?

Comment: @Jayden: OK, the goal was unclear. I amended the code.

Comment: Is there anything missing? Because the code you amended just now I tried, it didn't write anything to text file

Comment: @Jayden: fixed argument order for `fgets()` and missing `,` in `fseek`... tested on my system

Comment: Oh right.. Thank you for your helping.. It means a lot to me

Comment: Hi again, may I know what is the meaning of `0L` in `fseek`?

Comment: `0L` means `0` with type `long int` which is the expected type for the offset argument for `fseek()`. `SEEK_CUR` means that the offset is relative to the current position. Hence `fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_CUR)` does not move the stream pointer but allows changing from reading to writing to the stream open in update mode.

Comment: I see.. Is it okay if I remove `fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_CUR)`? Since `a+` is reading and appending mode already, so no need use `fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_CUR)` change to writing mode.

Comment: Quoting the C Standard: **7.21.5.3 the `fopen` function** [...] *When a file is opened with update mode (’+’ as the second or third character in the above list of mode argument values), both input and output may be performed on the associated stream. However, output shall not be directly followed by input without an intervening call to the fflush function or to a file positioning function (fseek, fsetpos, or rewind), and input shall not be directly followed by output without an intervening call to a file positioning function, unless the input operation encounters end-of-file.*

Comment: So indeed the `fseek()` is not needed, because the previous loop encountered the end of file.  Be aware that this is a very special case.  It is good practice to always issue a `fseek()` when switching between reading from and writing to the stream and vice versa.

Comment: I see.. Thanks for your information